# How do you type a space on a set 3 keyboard?

Tags: final-consonant, spacing

How is space typed on set 3 keyboard?

It appears a main character takes the place of the space on a set 3 keyboard.

Comment: None of the 세벌식 (set 3) keyboards have character placed on the space bar. Could you give the example of the case you mentioned?

Comment: https://captainalan.github.io/language-and-linguistics/languages/korean/input.html

Comment: Have you mistaken o in the space bar as ㅇ? That symbol just mean 'Finger rest (initial) places', not the letter ㅇ. You can find all of two ㅇs on A and J in the other image

Answer (score 1):

In the 3-set keyboard (세벌식), the space is entered exactly same as the other usual keyboards.

You may have mistaken the 'O' sign meaning the finger position as the character 'O' as @Bihrang pointed out.